# Spring expression language not working with spring aop

Tags: spring, spring-aop

```
<bean id="eddie" class="com.springinaction.Instrumentalist">
    <property name="instrument" value="#{violin}"></property>
    <property name="song" value="#{kenny.song}"></property>

</bean>

<bean id="violin" class="com.springinaction.Violin">
</bean>


<bean id="kenny" class="com.springinaction.Instrumentalist">
    <property name="song" value="Kenny is a star,kenny is a star"></property>
    <property name="instrument" ref="saxopone"></property>
</bean>

<aop:config>

    <aop:aspect ref="audience">

        <aop:before pointcut="execution(* com.springinaction.Performer.perform(..))" method="takeSeats()"/>

        <aop:after-throwing method="demandRefund" pointcut="execution(* com.springinaction.Performer.perform(..))"/>

    </aop:aspect>

</aop:config>
```

In the above code,I am injecting `song` , `instrument` property of `eddie` bean using spring expression language. But, `song` property not injected properly..and i am getting the below error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'eddie'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [spring-config.xml]: Initialization of
>   bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException:
>   Expression parsing failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
>   EL1008E:(pos 6): Field or property
>   'song' cannot be found on object of
>   type '$Proxy4'    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>     at
>   com.springinaction.Main.main(Main.java:10)

Instrument property is injected properly where as song property is not injected and this is happening because of aop only..

when i comment out `<aop:config>` it is working fine..

Anything wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
...
</aop:config>
```

This way you get a dynamic subclass and the property should be available in the proxy created via Spring AOP.

The default behaviour of Spring AOP is to create a Java proxy for the interfaces, so the properties of any classes won't be accessible through the proxy.

Comment: Yes, it is working..
thanks for your time Timo..

Spring AOP really eating my brain :)

Comment: `Spring in Action` book does not talk about all these details.I think i have to read spring reference..